# Git Rebasing onto generated files (auto solving remove/change conflict by removing)

Tags: git

I work in a company where one team constantly includes generated executable (and bunch of other garbage) with each commit. Due to non-technical reasons, I have to constantly rebase our work on top of theirs.

This is how it looks most days for me:

```
   -----C------TNC--(their_branch)
         \
          \----CC--(master)
```

TNC (their new commits) contains:

- some useful changes
- a lot of garbage

CC (cleanup commit) contains:

- added .gitignore
- rm a-lot-of-garbage-*

Now, I want to do:

```
 (on master)$ git rebase their_branch
```

This, of course, throws a conflict (changed, removed). Since this is almost daily task, I want to do it without hustle (it is enough that this redefines our whole history every time). So I tried:

```
 (on master)$ git rebase their_branch -s recursive -X ours
```

According to the [Git manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_merge_strategies), this should force "conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring our version. Changes from the other tree that do not conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a binary file, the entire contents are taken from our side." But it doesn't - it still stops and asks me to resolve conflicts. I have been running a script removing files, but it is annoying.

Can Git just force the removal of binary files?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with git `filter-branch`? I think it would work but am not that familiar with actually using it. The general approach would be to first call filter-branch to remove the generated files, then rebase on top of the filtered branch.

Comment: @ma_il I have tried some things. But in general, there SHOULD be more generic approach. I want to use rebase, not to hack it. I already have a script solving the problem, but wondering if there is a 'real way' to do this.

Comment: Imho the "real way" to do this is to not check in the generated files in the first place :)

Comment: @ma_il Agreed - but that does not answer my question...

Comment: @zmilojko: I share your pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your very specific set of your circumstances such as taking your side of all the changes including file removals on your branch, you can proceed along the following lines. Generally speaking though it is better to always resolve rebases manually.

```
# attempt a rebase, expect it to fail
$ git rebase their_branch

# take our side of all files that changed on their_branch and master branch,
# expect resolution to fail for renames (renames include file deletions) still;
# also note the meaning of `theirs` and ‘ours’ is reversed for a rebase.
$ git checkout --theirs -- .

# tell git that conflicts have been resolved (after we took our side)
$ git add -A

# explicitly take our side of all deletes
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=UD | xargs -n1 git rm

# proceed to rebase our changes, expect this to succeed
$ git rebase –continue && echo “SUCCESS!”
```

All of that can be arranged into one command, alias or a shell function:

```
$ git rebase their_branch || ((git checkout --theirs -- . \
|| (git diff --name-only --diff-filter=UD | xargs -n1 git rm) && git add -A) \
&& git rebase --continue)
```

If your rebase happen to be successful the `||` will avoid the superfluous scripted resolution, stopping at the very first state where your rebase succeeds, as appropriate.

Here’s a toy example to boot, to illustrate rebase of file removals,

```
# their_branch = master, our dev branch = foo
$ cd /tmp/toy-repo
$ git init . && touch README && git add README && git commit -m "add README"
$ git checkout -b foo && git rm README && git commit -m "rm README"
$ git checkout master && echo "changing README" >> README && git add README && git commit -m "modify README"
$ git checkout foo && git rebase master || ((git checkout --theirs -- . || (git diff --name-only --diff-filter=UD | xargs -n1 git rm) && git add -A) && git rebase --continue)
$ git log
a3730c5 rm README // on foo, rebased
55c9074 modify README // on master
1fa1398 add README // on master
```